# No such file error in command substitution bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script

```
#! /bin/bash 

command='echo "hello world" '
timeout=10
cli_raw_output="$(timeout ${timeout} "${command}" 2>&1)" 
echo "$cli_raw_output"
```

Here when I execute, it's giving the error as

> timeout: failed to run command `echo "hello world"   ': No such file
>   or directory

I understand that it's treating 'echo "hello world"' as a single word. 
But in these cases how do I execute it?

I can't remove the quotes around 'command' variable as I have to treat 'hello world'(it's a requirement) as a single word(not necessary in this echo case though).

Comment: you should use this=>  cli_raw_output=$(timeout $timeout $command 2>&1)  instead of=> cli_raw_output="$(timeout ${timeout} "${command}" 2>&1)"

Comment: @AkhilJalagam Same issue, it's sending "hello and world" instead of "hello world"